# Playing few audios one after another with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 audio files pre-loaded in javascript. 
My goal is when a button is pressed, play the first audio. 
2 seconds after the previous audio ended, play the next one.
I want to do all this with javascript only (except for calling the function).

Right now, I've only managed to play only the first one or three all at the same time. So I need help on this one.

HTML part:

```
<button onClick="rotatePrime(0);">Prime Slide Show</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var audioFile = new Array("a1.mp3","a2.mp3","a3.mp3");
var audio = new Array;

    for (i=0; i<audioFile.length; i++) {
      audio[i]= new Audio("Audio/"+audioFile[i]);
      audio[i].load();
    }

    function rotatePrime() {
            audio[0].play();
            audio[0].onended=setTimeout(function(){audio[1].play();}, 2000);
            audio[1].onended=setTimeout(function(){audio[2].play();}, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
audio[0].onended=function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  audio[1].play()
 ;}, 2000);
};
```

onended syntax:

```
object.onended=function(){myScript};
```

Comment: It works. Based on your code I finally managed to do it in for loop.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I'd appreciate if you mark my answer as "Answer".